# Prove that the following improper integral $\int_2^\infty x^5 \ln(x^5-1)-5x^5\ln x$ diverges

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

> Prove that the following improper integral $\int_2^\infty x^5 \ln(x^5-1)-5x^5\ln x$ diverges.

$Proof.$ by simplifying the integral we would get: $$\int _{2}^{\infty }\left( x^{5} \cdot \ln\left( x^{5} -1\right) -5x^{5}\ln( x)\right) dx=\lim _{M\rightarrow \infty }\int _{2}^{M}\left( x^{5}\left(\ln\left( x^{5} -1\right) -5\ln( x)\right)\right) dx\\
\\
=\lim _{M\rightarrow \infty }\int _{2}^{M}\left( x^{5}\left(\ln\left( x^{5} -1\right) -\ln\left( x^{5}\right)\right)\right) dx=\lim _{M\rightarrow \infty }\int _{2}^{M}\left( x^{5}\ln\left(\frac{x^{5} -1}{x^{5}}\right)\right) dx\\
\\
=\lim _{M\rightarrow \infty }\int _{2}^{M}\ln\left(\left(\frac{x^{5} -1}{x^{5}}\right)^{x^{5}}\right) dx=\lim _{M\rightarrow \infty }\int _{2}^{M}\ln\left(\left( 1-\frac{1}{x^{5}}\right)^{x^{5}}\right) dx\\
\\
\xrightarrow[x\rightarrow \infty ]{}\lim _{M\rightarrow \infty }\int _{1}^{M}\ln\left(\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)\right) dx=\lim _{M\rightarrow \infty }\int _{1}^{M} -1\\
\\
=\lim _{M\rightarrow \infty } -x\Bigl|_{2}^{M} =\lim _{M\rightarrow \infty } -M+2=-\infty $$

---

Now, I know that it easily diverges because the function has limit $L= \frac{1}{e}$ and it isn't zero. However, is what I have done still valid? or it is a critical mistake?  Thanks!

Comment: Derivation looks OK.  Simpler by using power series.  $x^5ln(1-\frac{1}{x^5})=-1+O(\frac{1}{x^5})$. So integral $\approx 2-M$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg so you are saying that this way is right?

Comment: the last line is not quite correct.  The integrand $(1-x^{-5})^{x^5}\approx \frac{1}{e}$ only for large $x$, which is sufficient for divergence.

Comment: @herbsteinberg so if for example, I would write it as a proof for a test, it is correct? because I can't still understand if this is mathematically correct.

Comment: @herbsteinberg so checking for large $x$ is sufficient for divergence, and that is why I could make the last line's steps?

Comment: Lower limit of integration should be large enough for approx.  integrand, so as $M\to \infty$ that part of the integral diverges.

Comment: @herbsteinberg but still can't understand if you are saying that we can go for large $x$ as I did in my proof.

Comment: For large $x$ the integrand goes to $-e^{-1}$.  However you can't use it for small $x$,  But it doesn't matter as $M\to \infty$ only large $x$ is important to show divergence,  $\int_2^M=\int_2^A+\int_A^M$, where $x\gt A$ approx holds and $\int_A^M\to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

As you started writing it $$x^5 \log(x^5-1)-5x^5\log( x)=x^5 \log(x^5-1)-x^5\log( x^5)=x^5\log \left(1-\frac{1}{x^5}\right)$$ When $x$ is large
$$x^5\log \left(1-\frac{1}{x^5}\right)=-1-\frac{1}{2 x^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^{10}}\right)$$
$$\int x^5\log \left(1-\frac{1}{x^5}\right)\,dx=-x+\frac{1}{8 x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^9}\right)$$

What does happen if you integrate for a large upper bound ?

Comment: So as herb steinberg said, what I have done for large $x$ is good? because you are doing this as well in your proof. Right?

Comment: @Chopin. I think that you made life much more complex thatn it is. I think thet doing what you did under the integral sign could be dangerous. Cheers :-)

Comment: You are totally right! but I still cannot understand whether it is mathematically correct or not :(